# How to inherit a red black tree from a normal bst

Tags: c++, algorithm, inheritance

I'm having a gigantic trouble with inheritance. I have a normal node as follows (please, ignore any typo in the code, I do not have it right now, but it compiles fine)

```
template<typename T>
class Node {
    Node<T> *parent, *left, *right;
    ...//simple methods
}
```

then, I implement a normal `BST` using the node I just created:

```
template<typename T>
class tree {
    virtual Node<T>* insert(T value);
    ...// other methods of tree
}
```

now I want to make a red black tree, but the code for it is almost the same, so I just try to override, say, insert:

```
template<typename T>
class rb_node : public node<T> {
    int color;
    ...//methods to retrieve and set the color as well the constructor
}
template<typename T>
class rb_tree : public tree<T> {
    Node<T> *insert(T value){
        auto z = (rb_node<T>*)tree<T>::insert(value);
        while(z->parent()->color() == RED)...
}
```

since I cast, the `z->parent()` is recognized as a `rb_node`, but the parent don't since it was constructed in the base class, so it does not have the `color()` method. How do I solve this problem that is killing me for almost two weeks??

Obs: if anyone need, my code is at https://github.com/dodonut/Algorithms/tree/master/Data_Structures.

I tried to override the variables of `node` to `rb_node` on constructor(but cannot cast `nullptr`), on the method inside `rb_node` to `return  rb_node`(but the signature of base class methods is different)

Comment: OT: stop using c-style casts.

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution might be to have the base `tree` class also take an optional `NodeType` template argument? As in

```
template<typename T, typename NodeT = Node<T>>
class tree
{
    ...
    virtual NodeT* insert(T const& value);
    ...
};
```

Then the sub-class could use its special `rb_node`:

```
template<typename T>
class rb_tree : public tree<T, rb_node<T>>
{
    ...
    rb_node<T>* insert(T const& value) override;
    ...
};
```

Comment: ... and that way OP can drop the whole runtime polymorphism thing.

Comment: But with that does not work for the node and rb_node. If I need to know the color of the parent, I could not do that, since parent is a node, not a rb_node, thus I cant complete the insert algorithm on rb_tree. Can't do the same thing of second template on my node because he does not recognize what is a node. Is there another way to do this? An way that does not mess with declaration if I want to use an rb_tree or a normal tree. Want something like rb_tree<int> and tree<int>. Is it possible?

Comment: @viniciusmoraes Maybe do the same thing with `Node`? CRTP is what it's called, in the case the template argument is exactly the deriving class.

Comment: @LogicStuff I've reaserched about the CRTP, and I think it would not solve my problem. Since I have and node<T> parent, if I make a T parent and pass rb_node<T> as T, how could I instanciate an normal tree<int>? parent would become an normal integer right?

Comment: @viniciusmoraes The problem here is that a regular tree has regular nodes, and rb tree has rb nodes. So if your tree class has e.g. `Node *root`, you cannot make a child class to have `RBNode *root`. One way out of this coundrum is to create an abstract tree class that doesn't mention `Node` anywhere, that both simple BST and RB tree would inherit (RB tree can CRTP-inherit simple BST, this is not a problem, as the user only sees the abstract tree class). Another way out is to ditch OOP altogether and use geneticity instead (like the standard containers).

Comment: @n.m. I have think in this possibility, but if I make the base class tree, the purpose of share code between simple BST and RB would be lost, it would be two repeated codes. Indeed, RB_TREE uses RB_NODE, and normal BST use simple NODE, with CRTP I would just make TREE having a template on which node to use, But duplicity on some code I would have. There is not a way to do this?

Comment: I don't see any code duplication in this scheme. If you do please ask a separate question about it.

Comment: @viniciusmoraes Perhaps the problem is your requirement(?) that the `rb_tree` class must be a BST? Why not make an *abstract* base tree class that uses *abstract* nodes. Then you make two different implementations of that abstract tree and node, one for the BST and one for the RB tree. For common functionality create another templated helper class (or a set of templated functions) that is used by both tree classes. Then when you want to create a third type of tree that uses the same interface, then it could also inherit from the abstract base tree class.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the problem that I see, is I would make the abstract methods but the code for bst and rb_tree are almost the same differing for rb_tree which has to make rotations. Thats all. Thats why I'm struggling to make this inheritance. And is not a requisit, but if I come across something like that, would I duplicate the code? I'm just training code for fun really, and I came with this problem.

Comment: CRTP should work without any code duplication. If you have tried CRTP can't avoid code duplication, ask a separate question with code you have tried.

Comment: @n.m. I’ll ask it. Thanks